# Grey screen using Dygraphs - R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dygraphs

I have a problem using Dygraphs with R Shiny. When the graph loads too much data, I get a grey screen. I guess there are new functions used in the package when the graph loads much information, like functions of aggregations...

So here is the error I see in the browser :

```
TypeError: s.toExponential is not a function
```

The error is in the file : `dygraph-combined.js` .

And then when it crashes :

```
Mon Sep 14 2015 11:49:23 GMT+0400: Connection closed. Info: {"type":"close","code":1006,"reason":"Sending error http status 404","wasClean":false}
```

Nothing special in my code, but you can test it with a working example here : https://github.com/Berthoros/test-dygraphs.git The only problem is I can't see if the same grey screen appears with my example, because my computer's not able to start it.

I've searched how to fix the problem with no success. Does anyone know how to make it out of this situation ?

Thanks ! :)